# Sharepoint internal site connection from Azure

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, azure, intranet

We have internal sharepoint 2010 site where user loads documents specific to some hotfixes and training.

From that portal we are syncying files in sharepoint 2003 and same we are showing on Internet facing site.

Now we are migrating our internal facing sites to asp.net 4.0  and hosting website on Azure trying to use services of sharepoint 2010 site directly. But since its internal website to organization and we do not want to be accessed externally, please provide suggestion to handle this situation.

Comment: Sounds like you need authentication/authorization.